# Java equivalent of an AJAX code

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I want to use an API in my app. In it's guide, it shows me to make a connection like this-

```
$.ajax(
{ type: "POST",
 url: baseUrl + "query/",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
headers: {
 "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
"ocp-apim-subscription-key": subscriptionKey
},
data: JSON.stringify({q: text, lang: "en"}), //text is a String variable
success: function(data) { prepareResponse(data); },
error: function() { respond(messageInternalError); } });﻿
```

I'm translating this call for android. I've used `HttpURLConnection` like this-

```
URL url = new URL(baseUrl + "query/");
HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Now I can use setRequestProperty() to set the Header and contentType part. But I don't know how to set the `data` and `dataType` part.

Please help me.

Comment: did you try reading the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl + "query/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // Set the headers
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("ocp-apim-subscription-key", subscriptionKey);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Create a JSON object to hold the data
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("q", text);
    jsonObj.put("lang", "eng");

    // Write JSON object
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(jsonObj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        // success, get result from server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } else {
        // error
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());  
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't there be `conn.connect();`?

Comment: You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection. Operations that depend on being connected, like getInputStream, getOutputStream, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.